# How to pass matrices as arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

When I try to pass matrices as arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize, there is always "shapes not aligned" error in Costfunction. But when I compute Costfunction alone, there is no error at all... I have also tried to to pass ndarrays as arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize, there is also no error.

I really have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

data=np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt',delimiter=",")

m,n=data.shape

pos=np.nonzero(data[:,2]==1)
neg=np.nonzero(data[:,2]==0)

plt.scatter( data[pos,0], data[pos,1],color='r')
plt.scatter( data[neg,0], data[neg,1])
plt.xlabel('Exam 1 score')
plt.ylabel('Exam 2 score')
plt.legend('Admitted', 'Not admitted')
plt.show()

X=np.concatenate( (np.ones([m,1]),data[:,0:2]) , axis=1 ) 
y=data[:,2]

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

X=np.asmatrix(X)
y=(np.asmatrix(y)).T

def Costfunction(theta,X,y):
    Term1 = -y.T*np.log( sigmoid(X.dot(theta)) ) 
    Term2 = (1-y.T)*np.log( 1-sigmoid(X.dot(theta)) )
    return (Term1 - Term2)/m    
#
theta0= np.zeros([3,1]) 
print Costfunction(theta0,X,y)
#
res = minimize(Costfunction,x0=theta0,args=(X,y),method='Nelder-Mead')
print res
```

Part of 'ex2data1.txt'.

```
    34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
    30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
    35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
    60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
    79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
    45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
    61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
    75.02474556738889,46.55401354116538,1
    76.09878670226257,87.42056971926803,1
    84.43281996120035,43.53339331072109,1
    95.86155507093572,38.22527805795094,0
    75.01365838958247,30.60326323428011,0
    82.30705337399482,76.48196330235604,1
    69.36458875970939,97.71869196188608,1
    39.53833914367223,76.03681085115882,0
```

Comment: you should give us some example data-we can't load your textfile from your pc. At least post the shapes of each of the arguements

Comment: What is the shape of what `CostFunction` returns, compared to the shape its `theta` input?  My guess that it is calling the function correctly with `theta0`, but something changes as the `minimize` tries other values.

Comment: @hpaulj 'CostFunction' returns a matrix with only one element. I have also changed the type of the value 'CostFunction' returns, but the error is the same.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your reply. I have posted part of "ex2data1.txt".

Comment: `theta0` is a (3,1) array, right?  Check whether `minimize` can handle that, or whether it can only handle scalar functions.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I also tried to to pass ndarrays as arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize and also defined theta0 as a (3,1) array, there is no error.

Comment: If you found that a `matrix` will not work but an `ndarray` will, then why not define `X` and `y` as `ndarray`s? `X` already seems to be OK (1d array should be a 1d `ndarray`), and you can use `y=y[:,None]` instead of that `as_matrix`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you for your reply. I am just curious whether we can pass matrices as arguments, and what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I was trying to tell you: use a 2d `ndarray`. Does that not work?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, it works. I am a newbie to Python and more familiar with Matlab. So I want to know if we must use matrix, how should we code 'Costfunction' and call the 'mimization' function.

Comment: OK then. From someone who's also a newbie to python coming from matlab: efficient (and concise!) code often uses multidimensional arrays. I would suggest getting to grips with `ndarrays`, which provide a much more versatile arsenal of techniques, at the cost of losing matrix multiplications. But by also getting to grips with array broadcasting, the matrix multiplication `X*y` can be written as an `ndarray` operation of `np.sum(X*y,axis=1)`. (But you would lose the matrix power operation. Fortunately that's rarely needed. And you can always use `asarray`/`asmatrix` to convert back and forth.).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see :) Thank you for your detailed answer !

Comment: `np.dot()` does everything that a `np.matrix *` does.  The `np.matrix` class is just a convenience for lost MATLAB users. :)  Just remember that `np.array` can be 1d or even 0d.  `np.matrix` is like the 1990s MATLAB matrix - always 2d.